# Get a specific string from a service list using WSDiscovery

Tags: python, string, search, list, ws-discovery

I am using the WSDiscovery module for python. I have been able to search for services on my network. I am trying to discover a client and get the XAddress from this. The WSDiscovery module has very little documentation, actually so little the only piece is in the readme file of the module which is a few lines long. I have manged to get this specific code working below:

```
import WSDiscovery
from WSDiscovery import WSDiscovery

def printService():
    wsd = WSDiscovery()
    wsd.start()
    services = wsd.searchServices()
    for service in services:
        try:
            print service.getEPR() + ":" + str(service.getXAddrs())
            print service.getTypes()
        except:
            print "Error with "+service.getEPR()

    wsd.stop()
```

This get's all services and I can get different XAddresses using:

```
service.getXAddrs()[0]
```

But I am looking for one in particular with a specific id. The one of the addresses would come up as:

```
4yr8343-r48d-3ref-4fsw-5r4tw432:[u'http://10.10.10.10:5321']
```

Can anyone think of a suggestion to select the address with this id number for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [sources](http://code.google.com/p/python-ws-discovery/source/browse/trunk/WSDiscovery.py?r=2) you could see that

1.
searchServices signature has few parameters:

```
def searchServices(self, types=None, scopes=None, timeout=3)
```

and i don't think filtering by types\scopes can be useful, isn't it?

2.
service CLASS has those parameters:

```
class Service:

def __init__(self, types, scopes, xAddrs, epr, instanceId):
    self.__types = types
    self.__scopes = scopes
    self.__xAddrs = xAddrs
    self.__epr = epr
    self.__instanceId = instanceId
    self.__messageNumber = 0
    self.__metadataVersion = 1
```

For what i see, the only thing you could do is iterate over services retrieved by searchServices and filter by one of the attributes available.

Comment: @systempuntoout -- Yeah, it look's that way. I suppose I could look through each service in the for loop and match by string. Can you think of any other way's apart from the for loop?

Comment: @chrissygormley I can't :). Looking at the source code, matching by string seems the only path available.